# Affine resolution of quasi-affine surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a smooth quasi-affine surface over $\mathbb{C}$. Then is it true that there is a smooth affine surface $\bar{X}$ along with an open immersion $X \to \bar{X}$. 
By quasi-affine we mean $X$ is an open subscheme of an affine scheme. For example,  if $X$ is an open subscheme of an affine scheme so that the complement has finitely many closed codimension $2$ then can we choose $\bar{X}$ as affine smooth surface?